# Dynamic initialization code

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good morning in my timezone.

What is the best way to initialize an array conditionally ?

```
var x = [{X:1},{y:4},
              if(...)
                 {t:9},
           {z:7}
        ];
```

This will not work of course but what is the best way to do it with the minimun lines of code, i do not like this solution for example

```
vax x;
   if(...){
     x = [{X:1},{y:4},{t:9},{z:7}];
   }else{ 
     x = [{X:1},{y:4},{z:7}];
   }
```

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Do you care about the order? If so, you can init the array first, then use `Array.slice` and `Array.concat` to add an element inside; If not, just call `Array.push` to add a new element.

Comment: `var x = (0 === 1) ? [{X:1},{y:4},{t:9},{z:7}] : [{X:1},{y:4},{z:7}];` - of course you would want to change `0 === 1` to whatever boolean expression makes sense.

Comment: Thanks very much all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to

```
var x = [{X:1},{y:4}];
if(...)
x.push({t:9});

x.push({z:7});
```